# any demo for statsmodels regression model in crossvalidation setting?

Tags: pandas, regression, jupyter-notebook, statsmodels, cross-validation

I want to learn multiple linear regression model for my data frame. Below is demo code.  Everywhere on internet I only found as such code where target variable can be learned with other variables but on complete data set. I do not specifically found k-fold cross validation set up preferably a direct function as parameter to ols method.

I did however found crossvalidation setup in regression method from scikit-learn library, but I wonder why not with statsmodels.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm
import pandas
```

Assuming data was in .csv format and read using pandas (therefore, in data frame format).

```
mod = sm.ols(formula='Target_Var ~ var_1 + var_2 + var_3', data=df)
res = mod.fit()
print res.summary()
```